# Arduino potentiometer time control

Tags: c++, time, arduino

I want to set a time interval by a potentiometer. I want to select it from 1 to 6 seconds. How can I do this?

I have this so far. If I use the potentiometer the light goes from light to dark.

(I'm using Arduino Uno and I'm programming in C++).

```
const byte pot = 0;
int potWert=0;

potWert = analogRead(pot);  
analogWrite(led,potWert/4);
Serial.println((byte)potWert); //just for output on the serial monitor
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Use potWert to configure your timer.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but you are not using C++. The Arduino language base on C++, but it is not.

Comment: The Arduino language is C++. If you do not believe it change the IDE settings to verbose and see how gcc compiles.

Comment: Arduino language lacks (dynamic memory allocation) new and delete. These are part of the c++ (11,03,99) standard.

Comment: The language is actually called Processing. A C derivative originally intended for artists making visual performances with computers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

analogRead reads a range of *0 to 1023*. **You need to scale this to your time interval.**

You said you want the range 1 to 6 seconds (not 0 to 6?). To get this to scale properly to the pot you need to divide 1023 by 6 (7 if you need the the range 0 to 6). So:

```
1023 / 6 = 170.5
```

thus you need to use:

```
analogWrite(led,potWert/170.5);
```

Say you wanted it accurate down to ten millisecond units

```
 1023 / 600 = 1.705
```

Thus:

```
analogWrite(led,potWert/1.705);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the hard way, and makes the code hard to read. Use the map statement. Here's an example from the Arduino reference:

Example

```
/* Map an analog value to 8 bits (0 to 255) */
void setup() {}

void loop()
{
  int val = analogRead(0);
  val = map(val, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  analogWrite(9, val);
}
```